# Trigger with cursor for auditing

Tags: mysql, triggers, cursor

What I'm trying to do here is to create dynamic trigger:

1. Get column names from table called *original_table*
2. Iterate through the returned column names.
3. If there is a change between old and new values associated with the column name, update log table.

I'm getting this error message: `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'column_name' in 'NEW'`

If I manually type column names then it works but in that case this approach becomes static which depends on human interaction.

**TRIGGER:**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS log_original_table $$

CREATE TRIGGER log_original_table AFTER UPDATE ON original_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE column_name VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'original_table';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN column_cursor;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH column_cursor INTO column_name;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF (NEW.column_name <> OLD.column_name) THEN
            INSERT INTO original_table_log
                (parent_id, parent_field_name, parent_old_value, parent_new_value, parent_modified_on)
            VALUES
                (NEW.id, column_name, OLD.column_name, NEW.column_name, NOW());
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

  CLOSE column_cursor;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**ORIGINAL_TABLE:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `original_table`;
CREATE TABLE `original_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of original_table
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `original_table` VALUES ('1', 'michael', 'jakson', 'you');
INSERT INTO `original_table` VALUES ('2', 'john', 'travolta', 'me');
INSERT INTO `original_table` VALUES ('3', 'lionel', 'messi', 'her');
INSERT INTO `original_table` VALUES ('4', 'brian', 'adams', 'they');
```

**ORIGINAL_TABLE_LOG:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `original_table_log`;
CREATE TABLE `original_table_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_field_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_old_value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_new_value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_modified_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: show us please the result of `desc original_table`

Answer (score -1):

There are no columns named `column_name` in your `original_table` so you can do anything like `NEW.COLUMN_NAME` or `OLD.COLUMN_NAME`. You should do `NEW.First_name` for example